# Cant implement navigation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I'm writing an application on `Xamarin.Forms`. There is a main form and it is possible to move from it to other representations. The problem is that I could not use the page navigation. How it can be implemented? `ViewModel` I have as a library is. I threw commands on it, using `MvvmLightLibs`. All the information I saw gives an example using `INavigation`, but it's not visible in `ViewModel`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement a `NavigationService` yourself, there is none available out of the box in MvvmLight for Xamarin.Forms. However, implementing such service is quite simple, just a few methods can suffice. I suggest you check [this blogpost](https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/xamarin-forms-with-mvvm-light/) which has a walkthrough for building a simple Xamarin.Forms + MvvmLight app.

The key is to create an interface like `INavigationService` that will have methods like `NavigateTo` and `GoBack`. Then you create a class that implements this interface and uses a root `NavigationPage` to navigate throughout the app. At startup, you create an instance of `NavigationService` and pass in the instance of `NavigationPage` it will work with.

If you register the instance with `SimpleIoc`, you can then utilize constructor injection - in your view model you add `INavigationService` parameter to the constructor and the framework will pass-in the instance you have registered.

All this is demonstrated in the above linked blogpost, so it is a good starting point.

Another good source for learning is [this Xamarin Show](https://youtu.be/JH6-bho1ipo) episode where Laurent Bugnion, creator of MvvmLight himself shows how to use the framework with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Maybe another nuGets has that functions?

Comment: In the end however you still will have to pass in you Navigation Page in anyway. I think following  one of the tutorials first and then recreating it in your solution is the best way